# Sum purchased & sold quantities for all items on daily/weekly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables Items, DimDate, Purchase and Sales for items definitions, calendar table, purchased and sold Items respectively. [Tables structure here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/da63c/9)

I need to outer join sum(Purchased_Qty) and sum(Sales_Qty) with a date range, and also with the Items table so that the results would display as follows:

```
Date, Items.Product_Name, Sum(purchased_Qty), Sum(sold_Qty) 
group by [Date], Items.Product_Name.
```

I need to display purchased & sold quantities for all items and for all days of a date range.

[THIS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/da63c/4) is an example of a possible starting point query, i tried several combinations of joins & sub queries on query in this example, but none of them is correct in logic as i tested them.

Comment: When you say "I cannot join properly to get correct results," you don't specify what your problem is. Can you provide more detail as to exactly what's causing a problem?

Comment: One possibility: If you're joining each of the three transaction tables to the `Products` and/or calendar date tables, your totals may be too high. This would be due to the fact that for a given product and date record, SQL would provide a *cross-product* of the matching rows from the three transaction tables, leading to those totals being multiplied by the number of matching rows (when more than one matches). See my [answer to this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177061/116653), and see if it helps any.

Comment: @RDFozz the possibility is typical ! the totals are too high when more than a match occur. I read your answer to the other question, your explanation how DB engine works is thorough, thank you. however am still unable to think a solution through. may be some sleep will help.

sp_BlitzErik i'll work on some sample data when i wake up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to display purchased & sold quantities for **all items** and for **all days of a date range**.

According to this I applied Cartesian product between dimDates and Items using OUTER APPLY, that should return a combination of all dates and all items.

Then I've used two subqueries in the SELECT but you could LEFT JOIN Purchases and Sales tables.

> ```
> SELECT d.[Date], 
>        i.Product_Code, 
>        i.Product_Name,
>        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Purchased_Qty)
>                  FROM   dbo.Purchase
>                  WHERE  Product_Code = i.Product_Code
>                  AND    Purchase_Date = d.Date), 0) Purchased,
>        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Sale_Qty)
>                  FROM   dbo.Sales
>                  WHERE  Product_Code = i.Product_Code
>                  AND    Sale_Date = d.Date), 0) Saled
> FROM   [dbo].[DimDate] d
> OUTER APPLY (
>             SELECT Product_Code, Product_Name
>             FROM   dbo.Items 
>             ) i            
> WHERE  d.[Date] >= '20180115'
> AND    d.[Date] <= '20180116';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                | Product_Code | Product_Name | Purchased | Saled
> :------------------ | :----------- | :----------- | :-------- | :----
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P1           | ProductA     | 26        | 20   
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P2           | ProductB     | 5         | 20   
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P3           | ProductC     | 20        | 40   
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P4           | ProductD     | 0         | 0    
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P5           | ProductE     | 0         | 0    
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P1           | ProductA     | 15        | 21   
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P2           | ProductB     | 37        | 22   
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P3           | ProductC     | 23        | 3    
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P4           | ProductD     | 0         | 0    
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P5           | ProductE     | 0         | 0
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @Start_Date date = '20180115';
> DECLARE @End_Date date = '20180116';
>
> SELECT d.[Date], 
>        i.Product_Code, 
>        i.Product_Name,
>        COALESCE(p.Purchased_Qty, 0) Purchased_Qty,
>        COALESCE(s.Sale_Qty, 0) Sale_Qty
> FROM   [dbo].[DimDate] d
> OUTER APPLY (
>             SELECT Product_Code, Product_Name
>             FROM   dbo.Items 
>             ) i
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT Product_Code, Purchase_Date, SUM(Purchased_Qty) Purchased_Qty
>            FROM   dbo.Purchase
>            WHERE  Purchase_Date >= @Start_Date
>            AND    Purchase_Date <= @End_Date
>            GROUP BY Product_Code, Purchase_Date) p
> ON p.Product_Code = i.Product_Code
> AND p.Purchase_Date = d.[Date]
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT Product_Code, Sale_Date, SUM(Sale_Qty) Sale_Qty
>            FROM   dbo.Sales
>            WHERE  Sale_Date >= @Start_Date
>            AND    Sale_Date <= @End_Date
>            GROUP BY Product_Code, Sale_Date) s
> ON s.Product_Code = i.Product_Code
> AND s.Sale_Date = d.[Date]
> WHERE  d.[Date] >= @Start_Date
> AND    d.[Date] <= @End_Date
> ORDER BY d.[Date], i.Product_Code;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                | Product_Code | Product_Name | Purchased_Qty | Sale_Qty
> :------------------ | :----------- | :----------- | :------------ | :-------
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P1           | ProductA     | 26            | 20      
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P2           | ProductB     | 5             | 20      
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P3           | ProductC     | 20            | 40      
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P4           | ProductD     | 0             | 0       
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 | P5           | ProductE     | 0             | 0       
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P1           | ProductA     | 15            | 21      
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P2           | ProductB     | 37            | 22      
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P3           | ProductC     | 23            | 3       
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P4           | ProductD     | 0             | 0       
> 16/01/2018 00:00:00 | P5           | ProductE     | 0             | 0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=04b624251b8275d7d5de2d280ee837b5)*

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess, but I think you are after something a little bit like this;

```
Select i.name, sqty, p.date, pqty 
From
    (Select sum(purchased) as pqty, item, date
     From 
         Purchases
     Group by item, date
    ) p
  Left Outer Join 
    (Select sum(sold) as sqty, item, date
     From 
         Sales
     Group by item, date
    ) s On s.item = p.item and s.date = p.date
  Join 
    items i On i.id = p.item
 ;
```